# Missing following properties while rewriting react function from js to ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am rewriting my `js` project to `typescript` with react and I have the following function to create `dataContext` which I try to rewrite:

`javascript version`

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react'

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
    const Context = React.createContext()

    const Provider = ({children}) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue)

        const boundActions = {}
        for (let key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch)
        }

        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }

    return {Context, Provider}
}
```

And here is my `typescript version`

```
import React, {useReducer, createContext, ReactNode} from 'react'

export default (reducer: any, actions: any, defaultValue: any) => {
    const Context = createContext(defaultValue)

    const Provider = (children: ReactNode) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue)

        const boundActions: any = {}
        for (let key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch)
        }

        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }

    return {Context, Provider}
}
```

I get the following error which I do not know how to solve. I tried some other types on `children` like `ReactNode[]`, `JsxElement[]`, `Element[]` etc but nothing works.

```
Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ReactNode'.
  Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type, props
```

Comment: Try this: childern?: ReactNode

Comment: does not work :(

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo but in your JS version you correctly destructure an object in your Provider args but you are not doing this in the TS port:

```ts
const Provider = ({children}: {children: ReactNode}) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

1 way

```
const Provider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {...}
```

2 way

```
  interface IProviderProps extends React.PropswithChildren {}
  const Provider: React.FC<IProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {...}
```

3 way

```
  interface IProviderProps {
    children?: ReactNode | undefined;
  }
  const Provider: React.FC<IProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {...}
```

Comment: I get the error `Property children does not exist on type {}`

Comment: ok. Have you watched this example youtube.com/watch?v=Knes9ih5ObM ?